# Reading output of arecord in C with popen

Tags: c, linux, piping

I have tried to pipe the output of [arecord](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) using c:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{    
    FILE* file = popen("arecord -r 8000 --format S32_LE -D plughw:0,0 -d 4", "r");
    long buffer[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("./record.dat", "w+"); 
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<40000; i++){
        fscanf(file, "%ld", &buffer[i%100]);
        fprintf(fp,"%d\t%ld\n", i , buffer[i%100] ) ; 
    }

    pclose(file);
    fclose(fp) ;

    FILE *p = popen(GNUPLOT,"w");
    fprintf(p,"plot 'record.dat' lt rgb 'red' title 'yeag' \n");
    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

I have chosen "long" because of the "signed 32 bit" specification in the arecord command. However, gnuplot is showing me nonsense. Also the program finishes after milliseconds although I want to record for 4 seconds.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `arecord`? Are you sure it just prints a sequence of numbers and nothing more? Can you post the output of `arecord`? And do the numbers in `record.dat` match to the normal output of `arecord`?

Comment: The output of arecord in terminal is a lot of question marks and spaces. The program's output is "Record: WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate: 8000 Hz, mono" which makes me think that a need long.

Comment: So `arecord` dumps the binary values then? Then you cannot use `fscanf` because `fscanf` expects **text**, not binary. You'll need to use `fread` to read binary values.

Answer (score 3):

it seems like fscanf() is for text not for binary. Thanks to Pablo. A corrected version looks like:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){    
    FILE* file = popen("arecord -q -t raw -r 8000 --format S32_LE -D plughw:0,0 -d 4", "r");
    int32_t buffer[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("./record.dat", "w+"); 
    int i,k,s;

    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(int32_t), 100,  file);
        for (k=0; k<100; k++){
            s = k + 100 * i;
            fprintf(fp,"%d\t%d\n", s , buffer[k] ) ; 
        }    

    }

    pclose(file);
    fclose(fp) ;

    FILE *p = popen(GNUPLOT,"w");
    fprintf(p, "set xrange [3000:3400]\n");
    fprintf(p,"plot 'record.dat' lt rgb 'red' title 'raw' \n");
    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

which returns a beautiful plot:
[waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMig5.png)

Comment: When I execute the `arecord` line myself, I notice some ASCII characters at the beginning, `RIFF$<F4>^A^@WAVEfmt`. Perhaps you should first read the header and then the binary numbers. `file a` returns to me "RIFF (little-endian) data".

Comment: Also, `long` is incorrect type here. Use `int32_t`. Also use `-t raw` for non-RIFF .wav format but just raw samples without header.